# Replace digit in number if exists or push to end if it doesn't exist

Tags: javascript

Given the following data:

```
var x = 3
var number = 0621
```

How can I enumerate through number and try to find x digit in that number? If x exists in number, remove that number.

Can a integer be treated as an array?

Comment: You could use `.indexOf()` and the `.replace()` function... *"or push to end if it doesn't exist"* Push to the end of what?

Comment: `var y = ~~((number+'').replace(x+'',''))`

Comment: @ThinkingMedia - would love a breakdown of that bitwise operator

Comment: @ThinkingMedia have you tried your suggestion because I get an output of 401...

Comment: 0621 *is* 401 because the lead 0 makes it octal. use a string "0621"

Comment: ^ that, `console.log(0621)` would instantly get you `401`. It's not really clear what the OP is doing here ?

Comment: @mplungjan the `~` operator forces JavaScript to parse a value into a negative integer. Using two `~` just flips the value back to positive. It's shorter than writing `parseInt(x)`

Comment: @ThinkingMedia and much longer than writing `+stringValue` :D I still dont get why people insist on replacing `parseInt` (which is descriptive) with funky ways of parsing a string

Comment: Actually `~` the Tilde, is a bitwise NOT operator, it reverses the bits, making a `0` into a `1` and vice versa. For integers however it mostly works for also flipping to negative numbers, or the other way, hence the double NOT, but you should really know how it works before using it.

Comment: @Jamiec `+StringValue` can yield a float where as `~~` yields integer. Code readability is subjective. `!!"foobar" === true` code just shows you understand the JavaScript parser. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be careful. Number will be 401 as soon as you have assigned 0621 to it because of octal issues - extra tricky with the invalid octal numbers 08 and 09.

Instead make number a string and you can use charAt or indexOf:

```js
function chop(numString,num) {
  var pos = numString.indexOf(""+num); 
  if (pos ==-1) numString+=num; 
  else numString = numString.slice(0, pos) + numString.slice(pos+1);
  return numString;
}

var num = 0621;
console.log("Octal",num); // to show the octal issue

// better: 
console.log(chop("0621", 2));
console.log(chop("0621", 3));
```

Comment: Please see update. I was not sure if newer browsers handled 0nnn as octal or one had to do 0xnnn

Comment: Yep, its a good answer! That's why I upvoted it. I wasn't sure youd want me to update your answer with the correction or not.

Answer (score 0):

Would be some like this?

```js
var x = 3
var number = 0621;
var _new = '';
for (var t = 0; t < String(number).length; t++) {
  if (String(number).charAt(t) !== String(x)) _new += String(number).charAt(t);
}

console.log('and new', +_new);
```

Comment: No it would not. See the number becomes 401?

Comment: And your fiddle also did not process the numbers correctly. Please re-read the question

Comment: yes @mplungjan,  im spanish, so i dont get all the question. After saw your solution gives ms the idea of wich is problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Can a integer be treated as an array?

You can cast your `number` as a `string` then split it, this will give you an array.

> How can I enumerate through number and try to find x digit in that number? If x exists in number, remove that number

Now you can loop over the digits array to check if your inputted `x` is among them.

This is what you need:

```js
var x = 3
var number = 5783;
//This will give you an array with your digits
var arr = (String(number)).split('');

if (arr.indexOf(String(x)) === -1) {
  arr.push(x);
} else {
  arr = arr.map(function(n) {
    return n == x ? '' : n;
  });
}

console.log(arr.join(''));
```

**Note:**

Note that leading `0` in a `number` will give you unexpected resluts, so be careful about that.